# Getting NULL in SQL query as result

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

1. Lesson
2. Subject
3. Question

My query:

```
SELECT    
    LE.LessonId, LE.LessonName,
    SUB.SubjectName,
    QU.QuestionId, QU.QuestionName
FROM 
    Lesson LE
INNER JOIN 
    Subject SUB ON SUB.LessonId = LE.LessonId
INNER JOIN 
    Question QU ON QU.LessonId = LE.LessonId
WHERE 
    LE.LessonPageId = 1552
    AND SUB.IsActive = 1
    AND QU.IsActive = 1
```

I am getting the null result because of `"Question"` table is NULL.

But I want the result in spite of the `"Question"` table is NULL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting a "NULL" result.  You are getting an *empty* result set.  `NULL` is a value within a single column.

If this is the case, then you want `left join`.  This would look like:

```
SELECT LE.LessonId, LE.LessonName, SUB.SubjectName,
       QU.QuestionId, QU.QuestionName
FROM Lesson LE LEFT JOIN
     Subject SUB
     ON SUB.LessonId = LE.LessonId AND SUB.IsActive = 1 LEFT JOIN
     Question QU
     ON QU.LessonId = LE.LessonId AND QU.IsActive = 1
WHERE LE.LessonPageId = 1552;
```

Some comments.

When you use `LEFT JOIN` you pretty much should be using it for all joins (this is not true *all* the time, but it is good guidance).  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, even when the `ON` conditions would filter the results.

Also note that two of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause were moved to `ON` clauses.  This is needed -- otherwise the `WHERE` would filter out non-matching rows.

Comment: Thank you so much your guidance is really needful.